# Python - listening to two ports on a single script?

Tags: python

Is it possible to listen to two ports at the same time in a single python script? I tried the code here: http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/
but it only works with one port because socket.accept() is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple sockets like that, you'd have to set the TCP_NODELAY option on your sockets (see the setsockopt() function) and then use the select module to check to see when a socket is ready to be accepted, read, or written.

Comment: Can you provide an example for using select?